# How to parse a nested json object in postman which has dynamic keys?

Tags: json, postman

I have below JSON response coming from API, in which 104 and 2 are dynamically changing and I have these values already set in environmental varibales, e.g. {location_id} = 2, {account_id} = 104
Can anyone help on how to parse JSON and get the location object based on environment variable value for location id in postman tests section

```
{
    "104": {
        "2": [
            {
                "FirstName": "John",
                "LastName": "McClain",
                "Phone": "1234567890"
           }
        ],
        "3": [
            {
                "FirstName": "Rita",
                "LastName": "Maria",
                "Phone": "3092432345"
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clear up the question a little bit - I'm finding it different to see what you're asking. Where are you saving those env vars from?

Comment: Danny, i need to parse the above JSON but the keys like 2,3, are going to be dynamic, meaning they are based on a previous other API response.

Comment: Yeah I understand that - What are you trying to do with the parsed data. Are you trying to assert against the values of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very horrible and flaky way to 'test' the values from the response JSON in the question. This assumes that the `environment` vars that were set in the previous request were `account_id = 104` and `location_id = 3`. This does a **hardcoded** check to see that the `FirstName` property in that object, equals 'Rita'.

```
pm.test('Get the values', () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()[pm.environment.get('account_id')][pm.environment.get('location_id')]
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].FirstName).to.equal('Rita')
})
```

It's difficult to tell what you actually want to do with the data and this test isn't something that I would use but if you just wanted an insight into how you would parse the data based on some `environment` vars this is at least a starting point.

If more information is provided, I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Actually I am learning about postman scripting and was stuck to get object from response for writing further tests in the same script. 
All I needed was to get this object:

var jsonData = pm.response.json()[pm.environment.get('account_id')][pm.environment.get('location_id')]

Thanks it helped.